# @pause in .bat file prevents subprocess.Popen from finishing

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess

I'm trying to pipe the output of a simple .bat script to my python script using the following code (Win10 btw):

```py
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(C:\Users\Public\gamess-64\get-version-names.bat), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.communicate()
print(output)
```

The problem is that the script looks like this:

```
::
::   Mar   08, 2015 :: Sarom Leang :: get-version-names.bat
::
:: Looks in current directory for gamess.*.exe and outputs the
:: version names to be used in 'rungms.bat' or 'rungms-serial.bat'
::
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo ------                        -------
@echo Binary                        Version
@echo ======                        =======
@echo.
@for %%f in (gamess.*.exe) do @(
@set temp=%%~nf
@set version=!temp:gamess.=!
@echo %%f       !version!)
@echo.
@pause
```

The `@pause` prevents my py script from getting past `subprocess.pOpen()` so I wanted to know how to get the `stdout` without my script being stopped in it's tracks (And without just deleting the @pause).

Comment: Why do you need to keep the `pause`?

Comment: I don't. I can easily fix this in a number of ways to get where I'm going overall with this project. It's more of a curiosity thing: "Is it possible to get the stdout from .bat scripts with @pause commands? How do I circumvent this?"

Comment: Why do you even need the batch file.  The batch file is doing a very simple process that could easily be coded in Python in a few lines of code.

Comment: If pause is not wanted, but you don't want to get rid of it, and your output is being delayed because of it, the only thing left is to press any key. Your question seems therefore to be more about, how do I press any key in response to a pause, but I assume without bringing the screen to focus, and physically pressing a key.

Comment: Yeah that's it. I just though that it can't be that this method of getting the stdout (the only one anyone seems to be talking about) can be nuked by just writing @pause into a batch script. That seemed a bit silly to me.

Comment: A single `@echo off` line at the start of the batch would obviate the mechanical `@` at the start of each line.As for your bypass-the-pause problem, perhaps you could change the `pause` statement to `if not defined somevariablename pause`. That way, if you set the value of `somevariablename` before executing the batch, the `pause` would be bypassed, but if it's not set, execute the `pause`.

Comment: you may try to read text from `p.stdout.read()` without using `p.communicate()` but it may block and wait for end of data. And you can't send key press to `popen`. Evetually you may use `timeout` and `kill()` - `try: outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)  except TimeoutExpired: proc.kill()` See doc for [communicate](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

Comment: `output = proc.communicate(b'\n')`